# Python: Reverse Order Of Words

Tags: python, string, list

In my program I pull a string from another file and assign it to a variable (see below)

```
ex1 = 'John Doe'
```

How would I convert the above string to a different format as seen below? (Note the space after the comma)

```
ex2 = 'Doe, John'
```

Sorry if this question seems trivial but I haven't had much experience with lists and most solutions incorporate lists (so I don't fully understand them).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So is the exact problem to do this with only two words? Or can there be more?

Comment: Do you have certain guarantees about the string?  I.e. is it always first name, last name? Or could there be oddities like middle name as well?

Comment: So far I read a solution on another stackoverflow page saying something along the lines of: [" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in namelist]

Comment: @BenJones It is always in that format. No middle name or anything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case of 2 names, you can use `str.join` with `reversed` and `str.split`:

```
ex1 = 'John Doe'
ex2 = ', '.join(reversed(ex1.split()))  # 'Doe, John'
```

You can also use f-strings (Python 3.6+) via an anonymous function:

```
ex2 = (lambda x: f'{x[1]}, {x[0]}')(ex1.split())  # 'Doe, John'
```

It's not clear what you'd like to see for multiple names, e.g. if middle names are provided.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you will always have names in "First Last" format, here's a really simple solution:

```
name = ex1.split(' ')
ex2 = name[1] + ', ' + name[0]

>>> ex2
'Doe, John'
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
ex1 = 'John Doe Smith Brown'
print(', '.join(ex1.split(None, 1)[::-1]))
```

should do the trick.

The output is "Doe Smith Brown, John". If you actually wanted "Brown, Smith, Doe, John", remove that `, 1` parameter (which tells `.split()` to only allow one split).

Comment: Does this reverse the strings?

Comment: @BenJones Oops, forgot the slice operator from the example.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your example:

```
', '.join(ex1.split()[::-1])
```

Comment: ', '.join(reversed(ex1.split())) will do the same

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many answers posted, I would like to highlight Python multiple assignment schema and the newly-introduced *f-strings* (3.6+) which in your case could be used as:

```
name, surname = ex1.split(' ')
ex2 = f"{surname}, {name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 ext = ", ".join( reversed(ex1.split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
import re
ex2 = re.sub('(\w+)\s(\w+)', r'\2, \1', ex1)

>>> ex2
'Doe, John'
```